# Byte Buddy class is loaded but cannot be accessed using ClassLoader.load

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have created a new class with the following code:

```
//...name and fields etc
.make()
.load(NetworkClassManager.class.getClassLoader())
.getLoaded();
```

Which has created my class called `TestNetwork_ND`, but when I try access it using:

```
NetworkClassManager.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("TestNetwork_ND")
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestNetwork_ND
```

How can I load it onto the classpath properly so that I can access it in the above way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to inject the class.

```
.make()
.load(NetworkClassManager.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION)
            .getLoaded();
```

Using the `ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION`, loading strategy fixed it for me.

Comment: The default strategy is creating a wrapper class loader. The strategy you are now using is relying on sun.misc.Unsafe but as of Java 9, there is a safe alternative with the ClassLoadingStrategy.UsingLookup.

Comment: I shall remember this when/if I migrate to Java 9 :)